# Couldn't find tasksadmins with id=15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table

I have two controllers: Tasksadmins and Workers.

I defined a table, is called: Tasksadmin, and has the parameters: admin_email, worker_email, task, done. the done option is check box.

in Tasksadmins controller, I defined:

```
def edit
  @tasksadmin = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])
end
```

in this controller, I can edit all the row of the table. it works fine!

in the Workerscontroller, I tried to define:

```
def edit
  @tasksadmin = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])
end
```

I did it because I want to get all of the parameters of the row, but I will let the worker an option to change only the parameter of `done`.

unfortunately, I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WorkersController#edit
Couldn't find Worker with id=15
```

I think I got it because the url is: `localhost:3000/workers/15/edit`

(pay attention to: `workers`/15/edit)

in order to understand where the problem is, I wrote the next word in my `models/workers/edit.html.erb`:

```
hello!
```

so I think the problem is with the work `workers` in the url :/

how can I fix it please?

**UPDATE:**

this is the index of the `workerscontroller`:

```
def index
  @tasks_worker = Tasksadmin.where(:worker_mail => current_user.email)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @workers }
  end
end
```

this is `index.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Listing workers</h1>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Admin_mail</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Done</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>

   <% @tasks_worker.each do |task| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= task.admin_mail %></td>
      <td><%= task.task %></td>
      <td><%= task.done %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_worker_path(task) %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like the code you pasted is from Tasksadmin, but the exception raised is from trying to find a worker.

Comment: I am updating my topic with the index and edit pages.. please wait.. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line in Workerscontroller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:edit, :update]
```

and this line in Tasksadminscontroller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:update, :show]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Worker with ID=15 doesn't exist.

```
Worker.find(params[:id])
```

Will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if that Worker doesn't exist.

You can go into the rails console and try:

```
Worker.find(15)
```

If you want to have find return nil instead of raising you can use:

```
Worker.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Comment: ,I found it :/
Tasksadmin.find(15)
  Tasksadmin Load (5.2ms)  SELECT "tasksadmins".* FROM "tasksadmins" WHERE "tasksadmins"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
 => #<Tasksadmin id: 15, admin_mail: "admin2@gmail.com", worker_mail: "worker2@gmail.com", task: "feed the cat", done: false, created_at: "2013-01-01 19:39:03", updated_at: "2013-01-01 19:39:03">

Comment: What about Worker.find(15)

Comment: I think I found the problem (with cancan) I am trying to solve it.. thank you! I will update!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about this (maybe somebody can correct me), but I think

```
@tasksadmin = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])
```

just defines the variable `@tasksadmin`.

Now, if you call the `localhost:3000/workers/15/edit`-URL, Rails is actually searching for a worker with ID 15 (`Worker.find(15)`)

What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I think I found the problem (with cancan) I am trying to solve it.. thank you! I will update!